# Change text file output

Tags: python, regex, automation

I have two things that I would like to replace in my text files.

1. Add " " between String end with '@' (eg. ABC@) into (eg. A B C)
2. Ignore certain Strings end with 'H' or 'xx:xx:xx' (eg. 1111H - ignore), (eg. if is 1111, process into 'one one one one')

so far this is my code..

```
import re

dest1 = r"C:\\Users\CL\\Desktop\\Folder"
files = os.listdir(dest1)

#dictionary to process Int to Str
numbers = {"0":"ZERO ", "1":"ONE ", "2":"TWO ", "3":"THREE ", "4":"FOUR ", "5":"FIVE ", "6":"SIX ", "7":"SEVEN ", "8":"EIGHT ", "9":"NINE "}

for f in files:
    text= open(dest1+ "\\" + f,"r") 
    text_read = text.read()
    
    #num sub pattern
    text = re.sub('[%s]\s?' % ''.join(numbers), lambda x: numbers[x.group().strip()]+' ', text)

#write result to file
data = f.write(text) 

f.close()
```

sample .txt

```
1111H I have 11 ABC@ apples
11:12:00 I went to my@ room
```

output required

```
1111H I have ONE ONE A B C apples
11:12:00 I went to M Y room
```

also.. i realized when I write the new result, the format gets 'messy' without the breaks. not sure why.

```
#current output
ONE ONE ONE ONE H - I HAVE ONE ONE ABC@ APPLES 
ONE ONE ONE TWO H - I WENT TO MY@ ROOM

#overwritten output
ONE ONE ONE ONE H - I HAVE ONE ONE ABC@ APPLES ONE ONE ONE TWO H - I WENT TO MY@ ROOM
```

Comment: When you have a spare minute please check the answer below and provide feedback. The patterns to skip specific substrings might need adjusting, since you only provided single examples, and not exact specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
def process_match(x):
    if x.group(1):
        return " ".join(x.group(1).upper())
    elif x.group(2):
        return f'{numbers[x.group(2)] }'
    else:
        return x.group()

    
print(re.sub(r'\b(?:\d+[A-Z]+|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b|\b([A-Za-z]+)@|([0-9])', process_match, text_read))
# => 1111H I have ONE ONE  A B C apples
#    11:12:00 I went to M Y room
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgX6oy/1). The main idea behind this approach is to parse the string only once capturing or not parts of it, and process each match on the go, either returning it as is (if it was not captured) or converted chunks of text (if the text was captured).

*Regex details*:

- `\b(?:\d+[A-Z]+|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\b` - a word boundary, and then either one or more digits and one or more uppercase letters, or three occurrences of colon-separated double digits, and then a word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\b([A-Za-z]+)@` - Group 1: words with `@` at the end: a word boundary, then oneor more letters and a `@`
- `|`  - or
- `([0-9])` - Group 2: an ASCII digit.